# Submitting multiple formData objects with Fetch

Tags: javascript, forms, fetch

I'm creating a competition form where the user can submit multiple codes. Each code is a new entry

Currently I am looping through each of the codes, augmenting the `formData` object, and then sending it off with fetch. However, this seems messy - and I also can't easily check if it all succeeded or failed (which I want to do to change the HTML view).

How can I combine these into one fetch execution then clearly see if it failed or succeeded?

```
//loop through codes and submit one entry each.
let codes = document.querySelectorAll(".code-row");

for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
  let uniqueCode = codes[i].querySelector('input').value;
  let currentSubmission = new FormData(form);

  currentSubmission.set('code', uniqueCode);
  console.log('processing entry ' + i);

  fetch(scriptURL, { method: "POST", body: currentSubmission })
  .then((response) => console.log("Success!", response))
  .catch((error) => console.error("Error!", error.message));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think you can send multiple formData objects within the one post, you can group the promised together using `Promise.all()`. Here's my revised code:

```
let codes = document.querySelectorAll(".code-row");
const promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
  let uniqueCode = codes[i].querySelector('input').value;
  let currentSubmission = new FormData(form);

  currentSubmission.set('code', uniqueCode);

  let promise = fetch(scriptURL, { method: "POST", body: currentSubmission });
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then((response) => console.log("Success!", response))
.catch((error) => console.error("Error!", error.message))
```